# Как растянуть диаграмму на весь MSChart в c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Проблема следующего характера: есть Chart с большим набором точек, необходимо изобразить график. Высота Chart может быть аж 2-3 тысячи единиц. После загрузки точек в Chart добавляется по оси OY дополнительное поле. Я выставила в ChartArea свойство position как Height = 100 и Widht = 100, т.е. тем самым, график должен был растянуться на весь Chart, но поле почему-то все-равно есть. Из Chart мне необходимо было убрать видимость линеек осей и начало координат должно начинаться с левого верхнего угла (сделала AxisY.IsReversed = true). Так вот как убрать эти "сопли"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то мне сомнительно что явное указание Height = 100 и Widht = 100 приводит к растягиванию на всю доступную область... Это WPF или WinForm? Чарт из стандартных контролов или подключаемая библиотека?

Comment: @Alexey WinForms, стандартный Chart

Comment: Создал тестовый проект. Кинул на форму Chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart ). Создал тестовый метод, скопировал туда ваш код- мне компилятор ругается на событие chart.ChangingScale и все свойства chart к которым вы обращаетесь в коде, говорит нет таких у Chart'a.
Т.е. это либо не стандартный чарт, либо я какие-то либы забыл подключить...

Comment: @Alexey параметр указанный в конструкторе, это объект моего собственного класса, который содержит точки графика. все что с ним связано в коде, можно убрать и заполнить любыми точками. Конструктор содержится в классе : public sealed class _2DChart : Chart.

Comment: @Alexey немного перефразировала вопрос, прошу прощения за неясность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методом научного тыка нашёл свойство у Axis'ов которое отвечает за отображение черточек к которым стыкуются цифры...

В общем если выставить его в false то черточки пропадут:

```
 area.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
 area.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
```

А чтобы убрать отступы по краям необходимо сделать следующее (по аналогии с Position):
`area.InnerPlotPosition= new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);`

Comment: ц-ц-ц. таким образом черточки пропадут, но отступ останется. мне нужно убрать этот отступ сверху, который выделен красным цветом на рисунке.

Comment: @Нафиса обновил ответ.